# Angularjs table sort directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written the following directive for AngularJS, unfortunately not everything works.

```
myApp.directive("thsort", function() {
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    transclude : true,
    template : '<span ng-click="onClick()">' +
        '<span ng-transclude></span>{{column}}' +
        ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>' +
        //'<span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{\'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet\' : column == by && !descending,  \'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt\' : column==by && descending}"></span>'+
        '</span>',
    scope : {
        by : '='
    },
    link : function($scope) {
        $scope.onClick = function() {
            if ($scope.$parent.column == $scope.by) {
                $scope.$parent.descending = !$scope.$parent.descending;
            } else {
                $scope.$parent.column = $scope.by;
                $scope.$parent.descending = false;
            }
            //test
            $scope.$watch('column', function() {
                this.column = $scope.$parent.column;
            });
        };
    }
};});
```

Here is HTML Code:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th thsort by="'tName'">Name</th>
    <th thsort by="'tStart'">Start</th>
    <th thsort by="'tEnd'">Ende</th>
    <th thsort by="'tLocation'">Ort</th>
    <th thsort by="'sfName'">Verantwortlicher</th>
    <th thsort by="'tPublic'">Public?</th>
    <th></th>
</tr></thead>

<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:column:descending">
```

I have written the following directive for AngularJS, unfortunately not everything works.
Unfortunately it was not possible for me to Glyphicons and hide. Access to the $ scope. $ Parent for column and has not been possible by me. The icon has to be only displayed if the current line is being sorted. Happy DESC and ASC differ.

I would also like the directive "thsort" to "table" apply so that any "th" with "by" are automatically addressed. (Just a little embellishment)

I wanted to create me so a little help to be able to apply this directive to tables quickly and easily. May even between tables in the same scope.

Current status as plnkr.co

I am glad if someone can help me.

Comment: Can you translate the question to english? What I get is that you have built a `thsort` directive, but how does it break?

Comment: First step, I want to show the icons, if one column is selected. The out commented line. But I can't access the $scope.$parent.column from the template.

Comment: Why don't you use the OrderBy filter included in AngularJs ? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: I'm using `orderBy`... However, I do not want to add to each th-element `ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse=false" ...` and the logic to show and hide the sort glyphicon icons. [http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html)